# Delete a row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code which finds the excel row of an item from a list and deletes the items from a list. What I want... is to delete the Excel row as well.

The code is here

```
Private Sub imperecheaza_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rand As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")    
Rand = 3
Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value <> "" And Rand < 65000
   If ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = gksluri.Value * 1 And ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value = gksluri.List(gksluri.ListIndex, 1) * 1 Then
            ws.Range(Rand, 1).EntireRow.Delete '(here I want to delete the entire row that meets the criteria from the If statement)
            gksluri.RemoveItem gksluri.ListIndex
            Exit Do
    End If
Rand = Rand + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Where I added ws.Range(Rand,1).EntireRow.Delete is where I want to delete the entire row but I don't know how to do it. What I want... if it finds the same value in a cell like in some selected item of my list to be able to remove both the entire row in excel and the item from the listbox. It works to remove the item from the listbox but I don't know how to remove the row as well

Comment: Warning. If you delete more than one row in a loop (running from top to the bottom), make sure that you ***reverse*** the loop, going from the bottom to the top. Otherwise your loop will skip the row just after the one you deleted. By changing the loop from bottom to top, you will prevent this (at the cost of double checking after each deleted row).

Comment: This skipping can also be avoided by setting your if statement to only increment when a row is not deleted.

Comment: @Wayne, Absolutely true! In the end "All roads lead to Rome". Your solution is more elegant and will be faster when there are many rows that need deleting. My main concern was that people are aware of the skipping rows problem when plowing through a file and deleting rows.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Chris Nielsen's solution is simple and will work well. A slightly shorter option would be...

```
ws.Rows(Rand).Delete
```

...note there is no need to specify a Shift when deleting a row as, by definition, it's not possible to shift left

Incidentally, my preferred method for deleting rows is to use...

```
ws.Rows(Rand) = ""
```

...in the initial loop. I then use a Sort function to push these rows to the bottom of the data. The main reason for this is because deleting single rows can be a very slow procedure (if you are deleting >100). It also ensures nothing gets missed as per Robert Ilbrink's comment

You can learn the code for sorting by recording a macro and reducing the code as demonstrated in this [expert Excel video](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/vba-record-macros.php). I have a suspicion that the neatest method (Range("A1:Z10").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlSortAscending/Descending, Header:=xlYes/No) can only be discovered on pre-2007 versions of Excel...but you can always reduce the 2007/2010 equivalent code

Couple more points...if your list is not already sorted by a column and you wish to retain the order, you can stick the row number 'Rand' in a spare column to the right of each row as you loop through. You would then sort by that comment and eliminate it

If your data rows contain formatting, you may wish to find the end of the new data range and delete the rows that you cleared earlier. That's to keep the file size down. Note that a single large delete at the end of the procedure will not impair your code's performance in the same way that deleting single rows does

Comment: Is the `.delete` preferred over `.rows()=''` in excel vba to truncate cells? Which one is faster?

Answer (score 7):

Change your line

```
ws.Range(Rand, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

to

```
ws.Cells(Rand, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 5):

Better yet, use union to grab all the rows you want to delete, then delete them all at once. The rows need not be continuous.

```
dim rng as range
dim rDel as range

for each rng in {the range you're searching}
   if {Conditions to be met} = true then
      if not rDel is nothing then
         set rDel = union(rng,rDel)
      else
         set rDel = rng
      end if
   end if
 next
 
 rDel.entirerow.delete
```

That way you don't have to worry about sorting or things being at the bottom.

Comment: I think this is a correction - 'if not rng is nothing' should be 'if not rdel is nothing'? Nonetheless, thank you for this answer - by far the simplest to implement of the several that I looked through.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this will do it:

```
Rows("12:12").Select
Selection.Delete
```

So in your code it would look like something like this:

```
Rows(CStr(rand) & ":" & CStr(rand)).Select
Selection.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks... I get an error (Expected: End of statement) for the Shift:=xlUp

Comment: @andrei You can just remove the Shift:=xlUp. - and I have edited the code to be VBA friendly (thanks to the anonymous downvoter)

Comment: Note that selecting cells, ranges, rows et al before acting upon them is much slower than just acting directly upon them.