# Excel Marcro - delete a row based on row number

Tags: excel, vba

please help..i need a macro to delete specific rows based on row number (line number) for example, if i want to delete the the 2nd,9th,20th,150th rows, how it can be done in macro, please provide a macro where i can copy and paste the line numbers in the code and run from module. i have the row numbers in sheet2 Column A which are the rows to be deleted from sheet1

Comment: you will need to checkout this [Delete a row in Excel VBA][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851859/delete-a-row-in-excel-vba

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

for one row:

```
Rows(4).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

For multiple rows:

```
Union(Rows(4), Rows(7)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

For your specific case to allow to dynamically delete rows based on a list of row numbers in a source sheet. Change SourceWks to the worksheet where the numbers are stored and deletedWks to the worksheet where the rows are going to be deleted.

```
Dim deleteRows As Range
Dim data() As Variant
Dim i As Double

Dim SourceWks As Worksheet, deleteWks As Worksheet

Set SourceWks = Sheet2
Set deleteWks = Sheet1

    With SourceWks
        data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
    End With

    Set deleteRows = deleteWks.Rows(data(1, 1))

    For i = 2 To UBound(data, 1)

        Set deleteRows = Union(deleteRows, deleteWks.Rows(data(i, 1)))

    Next i

    deleteRows.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: hi philip A Barnes, im zero in vba, this works fine, but i have many specific rows, how do i do it? kindly help

Comment: @davidb: if you have many specific rows then use the second code sample where it deletes rows 4 and 7. Extend and change it how you want.

Comment: i have the row numbers which i want to delete in sheet2 column A, it is really time consuming entering one by one in the code, can u give me a code which reads the row numbers from sheet2 and delete the mentioned rows from sheet1?? i have the row numbers in sheet2 column A

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your above refinement.

Comment: your are great. it works like the way i wanted.thanks a lot.

Comment: great. Also its good practise to accept the answer you prefer so others know it has been completed.