# How can I delete a entire row using a find function?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data sheet that contains data for an apartment complex. I made userforms to add tenants, edit and delete them. however the way I am deleting them it leaves a gap in my data and it becomes very annoying to have to go in and delete all the rows by hand to keep the sheet looking clean.

```
Sheet1.Select

Dim FndRng As Range

Set FndRng = Sheet1.Columns("C:C").Find(What:=cboName.Value,    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then 'successful find
FndRng.Offset(0, -1).Value = ""
FndRng.Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 5).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 6).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 8).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 9).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 10).Value = ""
FndRng.Offset(0, 11).Value = ""

cboName.Value = ""
txtCode.Value = ""
cboGrade.Value = ""
txtPhone.Value = ""
txtDormitory.Value = ""
cboPhase.Value = ""
cboCourse.Value = ""
cboStatus.Value = ""
txtGrad.Value = ""
txtCsd.Value = ""
txtSsn.Value = ""
txtComments.Value = ""
cboSex.Value = ""

Else ' unable to find the value in "Name"
MsgBox "Name not found in Datasheet, Do not change the name while editing the profile.", , "Name not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

But as you can see that just leaves a big gap in the data.
I want to do something like

```
fndRng.row.delete
```

or something that meant that, if you can follow my thought process?

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a row in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851859/delete-a-row-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I had seen your suggested post but as furnished by Mrig, FndRng.EntireRow.Delete is what I was looking for. I knew what I wanted I just haven't used VBA in so long I was a bit foggy. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
fndRng.row.delete
```

use

```
FndRng.EntireRow.Delete
```